# Can't get rid of old data after copying fluid sim

Tags: baking, fluid-simulation, cache

**My situation**

I have a fluid sim in which a cube standing in a puddle
[image]

melts entirely into a puddle
[image]

To make the melting simulation more realistic i set the speed of the fluid sim to a very slow pace.

The next step is to add more fluid from an inflow. For this i want to make a new fluid simulation which already contains the final puddle of the melting simulation and grows from an inflow.

**My problem**
When i was trying to copy the final puddle of the melting animation and start a new one with it, it seems like the old baking data still remain.

To copy it i selected the puddle in the frame i needed it from and used shift + d to copy the object. Then i applied the fluid modifier to remove all its physics. I set a new domain and baked it again.

For some reason the new fluid sim still contains the cube of the old one, even tho the fluid object i copied and created isn't a cube.
[image]

**What i have tried so far to fix it**

- Removed all the simulation settings (including obstacle, fluid and domain) and set them new
- Removing the cache folder of the blender save files
- Renaming/Changing the save files locations
- Recalculating normals

**Here is my .blend file**
[image]

**Can anyone tell me where those old bake data come from and how i can get rid of them so i can finally get on with my life**

Comment: In the blend file you provided, you still have an object called "Ice Cube" with the fluid sim active (type "Fluid").  The object is set to non-visible / non-rendered, but it's there.  Remove the fluid sim from this object and the cube shape disappears when baking the sim (when I tried it).

Comment: @risingfall must have overlooked it multiple times, wow. Thanks for spotting it.